# Search list click page navigate use IONIC

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I am working on an ionic Chat application. I am struggling in the search of a data list in the backend. How to display the backend arraylist value, and how can I navigate the list value to another page momement.

Comment: Can you please share the code you currently have?

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. The SO community values when you show your own efforts, so you might want to add some code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask